# Note 7 WiFi keeps turning itself off

Tags: wi-fi, samsung

I really hope someone can help me, this is becoming infuriating. My Samsung Galaxy Note 7 keeps turning wifi off all on it's own. I have searched until blue in the face trying several things I've seen suggested on various forums. Nothing works. I wasn't able to track down another case of this happening on the Note 7, although I'd seen other phones from samsung as well as other manufacturers, but none of the fixes I came across worked for me.

I don't know what's triggering it, I've tried to watch it closely and see what the problem may be but can't seem to pinpoint it. Power Save mode is off, I set a static IP for it, turned off the smart switch feature which swaps between wifi and mobile network to "make sure you have the best signal", nothing works!!

Looking forward to any suggestions or fixes anyone may know of! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**First of all: return your device, it is at risk of exploding. See [this page](http://www.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-7).**

About the WiFi, Samsung has declared that it will turn off radios on Note 7s to prevent people from using them. See the post on this blog: https://9to5google.com/2016/12/07/samsung-note-7-radio-disable/.